# Codomain included in domain for a continuous function

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In *Problems and Solution in Mathematics* by Ta-Tsien.

$A$ is a connected, closed subspace of a compact Hausdorff space $X$, and suppose $f:A \rightarrow A$ is a continuous map. For each positive integer $n$ let $f^n(A)=f \circ \dots \circ f(A)$, $n$ times.

As part of the exercise solution, the authors "note" that $f^{n+1}(A)\subset f^n(A)\subset A$.

How does one prove it ? Which of the hypothesis are used to deduce this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f\colon A\to A$ we obviously have $f(A)\subseteq A$. Whenever $M\subseteq N$ we have $f(M)\subseteq f(N)$, in particular $f(f(A)) \subseteq f(A)$. Now your statement follows by induction.